# Hyper-V Virtual Machine Export/Import Woes

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, hyper-v, remote-desktop

I exported a virtual and imported it from a new folder location.  When I imported it, I select to copy the virtual machine (create a new ID).  I am trying to remote into it (before I exported, remote access was setup fine).  But I cannot access the VM from outside the machine anymore; I tried disabling/reenabling the local network connection and disabling the firewall.. nothing is working.  How do I get this to work again?

I can connect from the server though.  I'm on a homegroup network.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I needed to go into the device manager and enable the virtualized network adapter, and then everything was OK.